# $P_2 --> P_3$ Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: P_2 \to P_3$ be a transformation such that

$p(x)  \in P_2\mapsto  (x+10)p(x) \in P_3 $

1.Find the image of $p(x) = 5 + x - 3x^2$

2.Show that $T$ is a linear map
Can anyone show me how to proceed/solve such a task? Please link to ways of solving on youtube if you know of any.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of understanding the definitions.

(1) $T(p) = (x+10)(5+x-3x^2) = 5x + x^2 - 3x^3 + 50 +10x- 30x^2 = -3x^3 -29x^2 + 15x +50$.
(2) You need to show that $T(p+aq) = T(p) + aT(q)$ for any polynomials $p,q$ and scalar (real number) $a$. Just use the definition.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**

The map $T$ sends a polynomial of degree less than or equal to $2$, $p(x)$, to its product with the linear polynomial $(x+10)$.  Let's apply this to the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ as an example.

$$T(x^2+x+1)=(x+10)(x^2+x+1)=x^3+11x^2+11x+10$$

To show that the map is linear, we must show that it splits across sums, and constants can be pulled out.  In other words, suppose $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two polynomials and $c$ is a constant.  We need to show that $$T(p(x)+q(x))=T(p(x))+T(q(x))\\\text{and}\\T(c\cdot p(x))=c\cdot T(p(x))$$

To help get you started, notice that $T(p(x)+q(x))=(x+10)(p(x)+q(x))$.  See if you can calculate $T(p(x))$ and $T(q(x))$ and show that their sum is the same.